# Why do my svg look so blured when i zoom in my site?

Tags: svg, blur, blurry

Does anyone know what might be causing this and how to fix it? Thanks
I made the svg in last result page of this site https://connectedmarkets.uc.r.appspot.com/intro please visit last result page of this site my SVG look blurry when i zoom in like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB0fG.png)

Comment: Do you see this on all browsers?